# calculate using the number in 2D array: ValueError: math domain error

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

Want to do calculation using the numbers in 2D array

```
import math 
result = 0
data = [[0],[1],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[1]]
for i in data:
    result += (math.log(i[0], 2))
```

The reported error is `ValueError: math domain error`

Could someone show me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: You are trying to take `log` of 0 which is mathematically not possible.

Comment: @AKS Thanks for the reply. In this case, given numbers are all nonnegative.

Comment: Look at my other comment. The same logic applies for 0.

Comment: @AKS Thanks. A stupid question...

Answer (score 1):

> log 0 is undefined. It's not a real number, because you can never get zero by raising anything to the power of anything else. You can never reach zero, you can only approach it using an infinitely large and negative power. 3.

```
>>> math.log(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```